# Name of planar graph not containing series-parallel subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

Studying irreversible chemical reactions I've come across a type of directed graphs which must be easily recognizable but I'm not an expert. These are directed graphs with nodes {1,2,...n} and edges satisfying:

- If [a,b] is an edge then b>a
- Another property which is the one I cannot identify: essentially, there cannot be two vertices i,j (which represent specific reactions in the chain) that may "happen" (in real life) at the same time. I guess the proper way to state this is saying that there are no two proper series-parallel subgraphs but it may be simpler than that.

[typical reaction I study](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70zTU.jpg)

The picture shows the prototypical example: a chain of dependent reactions with possible branches BUT at any time there can only be an active reaction. A tree like this one:

```
    |
    o
   / \
  o   o  [THIS (or more complex) IS WHAT I WANT TO AVOID]
   \ /
    o
    |
```

is not allowed (the two "parallel" paths might happen at the same time and I am not covering that case).

Any idea about the name of these graphs/properties defining them?

Comment: The second condition seams to imply that the graph is a directed path. If one vertex has two different successor $i, j$, then I would expect that $i$ and $j$ could happen at the same time. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I do not know what a directed path is either... This is allowed. If you look at the image (I cannot insert, it is [liked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70zTU.jpg)). So you can have two successors or more but then each of them is connected with the lesser vertices...

Comment: Looking at your picture I think you can formalize your statement as "For all vertices $u, v$ there exists a path from $u$ to $v$ or from $v$ to $u$.". Here a path means a sequence of vertices which are connected by edgews, which are directed from the start to the end of the path.

Comment: I see, that seems quite reasonable and probably exactly what I need, I shall have to look at it in detail. Great answer, thanks. In case that is exactly what I need, do those graphs have a name? (Simply to use a fixed nomenclature if there is, no more than that).